# cPython for .NET API

Tags: python, .net, tcp, ironpython, cpython

I have build a bunch of python modules for controlling miscellaneous hardware over TCP. All is written for cPython (no .NET capabilities, as far as I understand).
I want to add a new instrument to the pool that comes with a .NET API. [See here](https://www.ap.com/technical-library/controlling-apx500-with-python/).

From the distributer of the API, only ironPython is mentioned as option for interfacing with the instrument.

I have no experience with .NET framework or ironPython, so I'm not sure what other options I might have (if any) and which suits my needs best.

My needs are: 
I want to use all my old cPython based modules along side with the new instrument and its .NET based API.

Staying in "normal" python would be the most elegant solution to me - but I'm really open for suggestions.

Comment: You mean you'e written C-extensions?

Comment: By cPython modules I mean "normal" python classes that run in any python3 interpreter just by importing them.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up porting my modules from cPython to ironPython.
This seemed to be a fairly straightforward job, and I'm pretty happy with the comparability.